# Delete file based on condition

Tags: files, gnu, delete

I have a directory of files with names similar to: `AA_1-000_S001_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz`

I would like to delete all files in a specified range, say: `S002` to `S010` in their names. Is there an easy way to do this? I am not able to find a simple solution so far.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this:

```
rm *S0{02..10}*
```

Comment: +1 Totally forgot that sequence expressions can be prefixed with 0.

Answer (score 0):

from 2 to 9

```
rm *_S00[2-9]_L*
```

for 10

```
rm *_S010_L*
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you very much! Is is possible to delete files with the range S1 to S200? I modified the code you provided but without success.